# How can I get the start positions of my regex matches from a string without also including the matches' length in the string itself?

Tags: python, regex

This is kind of a complicated question to explain and easier to just show as an example.

So let's say I have this string here:

```
exampleString = "abcauehafj['hello']jfa['hello']jasfjgafadsf"
```

And so we have the regex pattern of:

```
regex = r"\['hello'\]"
```

Now, what I want to do is get the start positions of regex matches within the exampleString. This would be [10, 22], which I currently calculate using the following code:

```
import re
matches = re.finditer(regex, exampleString)

start_pos = []
for match in matches:
    start_pos.append(match.start())
```

Now, the issue is, I do not want to include the length of the `['hello']` to the string itself. So the start_pos that I actually want would be [10, 13]. What would be the best way to do this without affecting the strings?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, but it did not work. I checked on regex101.com and the match start positions were still 10 and 22.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the positions 10 and 13 are the start positions of the matches within the string, but assuming the length of the matches themselves are not included. So each match is 9 characters long (including square brackets and single quotation marks), what I want is to not included these 9 characters so that I get [12,13] instead for the match start positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer a list comprehension, it's easy to do with `enumerate`, unless I misunderstood what you desired:

```
import re

exampleString = "abcauehafj['hello']jfa['hello']jasfjgafadsf"
regex = r"\['hello'\]"

start_pos = [match.start() - i * len(match.group()) for (i, match) in enumerate(re.finditer(regex, exampleString))]
```

Edit 1: of course, right after posting, I saw Kelly Bundy's comment stating exactly that...

Edit 2: just for the sake of it, I tried to wrap Kelly Bundy's variable length solution into a list comprehension; it's not pretty but at least it works ;)

```
exampleString = "abcauehafj['hi']jfa['there']jasfjgafads['hello']f"
regex = r"\['[a-z]*'\]"

start_pos = [match.start() - length_sum + len(match.group())
             for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer(regex, exampleString))
             if (length_sum := len(match.group()) + (length_sum if i else 0))]
```

Comment: Yeah, my own attempts at a list comp weren't pretty, either. [Best one](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBTsQwDEXFNqewuiAt0BFLNnMKlpkImanTJGqTKPVIA1dhMxs4FKehzZRKkIUV-X1_W__jK72xjeFy-TyxaZ--b27dmGJmyCQEnXFMAz1zdqGHPVT4esQTWTReSeuk9gaVZEuZ5j9OxvdosJtmSMMQpTaVyNTTeZ7N1UFJhe27vpMHXQkxIh8tTQuinXGhc0y5LvIH-LO5EWJizPyS4iJXAubnSzUxgwMXQD3qrVGcl-a6YgO-KB3cX8muuNaN_mfloV0FFLoFayHSfAjX2xnNNa41td_0fgA) I managed (note that CPython [optimizes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations) the for-clauses over those singleton-lists to mere assignments).

Comment: Nice one :) I didn't know about the `for` optimization, and in any case wouldn't have thought of using `for ... in [0]` to initialize my length_sum variable (I had a hard time until I thought of the ternary operator).

Answer (score 3):

You may use this:

```py
import re

exampleString = "abcauehafj['hello']jfa['hello']jasfjgafadsf"
regex = r"\['hello'\]"

matches = re.finditer(regex, exampleString)

start_pos = []
i = 0
for match in matches:
    start_pos.append(match.start() - i * len(match.group()))
    i = i + 1

print (start_pos)
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 13]
```

Here:

- We are using a counter `i` in the `for` loop
- We subtract `i` times length of the match from start position

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Do you happen to know how I could amend this to work in a list comprehension? I just am not certain how to increment the i value there. That would help it fit best in my code.

Comment: Sorry not clear to me. `i` is incrementing every time in loop as you can see in the code

Comment: https://ihoctot.com/python-list-comprehension-increment-counter so if you read in this link, it discusses how you can use `itertools.count().__next__` instead of `i+=1` in a list comprehension. But maybe I am overcomplicating it for myself.

Comment: @BobMcBobson Use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern allows variable-length matches:

```py
import re

exampleString = "abcauehafj['hi']jfa['there']jasfjgafads['hello']f"
regex = r"\['[a-z]*'\]"

matches = re.finditer(regex, exampleString)

start_pos = []
i = 0
for match in matches:
    i += match.start()
    start_pos.append(i)
    i -= match.end()

print(start_pos)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBBasMwEEXpdvbdC29kN7XpsgRyii4VUabxyJKxJSFPIOlVusmmPVRPU9lxAtVmxJ83_8P_-olntsFfLt9HNvXr78OjG2NILBIB0AnHONAbJ-c7sRMFfhzwSBZNr6R1UvcGlWRLifIfJ9N3aLCd8pKGIUhtCkjU0SnfpmKvpML6Uz_JvS4ARuSDpWleUWOcbx1TKhf8WfxLrgAmxsTvMcy40uDyeAETklhchPNitduCyM-Jze6qNMtlWS3y3aXBGMm3patWvL7hs5rzYs7l8s5X13bWkm5l_QE)):

```
[10, 13, 24]
```